# ASP .NET MVC - Uploading a file as part of main form entry

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a custom view page that contains an entry form (textboxes, dropdowns, and checkbox).  All the values that are entered are POSTed to a controller method via JavaScript.

How do I add the ability to upload a file to my form that can be POSTed along with rest of the data?  All the examples that I have found require a completely separate upload/POST for the file.

So far my HTML portion has:

```
<div>
    <h4>Files</h4>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Upload a file</legend>
        <input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple />
        <input type="button" id="fileButton" value="Upload Files" /><br />
        <img src="~/Content/Image/loading.gif" id="loadingImg" />    
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

And my corresponding JavaScript:

```
$("#fileButton").click(function () {
            var files = $("#fileInput").get(0).files;
            //var fileData = new FormData();

            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                fileData.append("fileInput", files[i]);

                alert(files[i]);
            }
        });
```

Comment: try this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: What prevents you from POSTing the form?

Comment: @EduardoMolteni - I am creating a JSON object with the form details and using that POST to the controller method.  I want to include the file also.

Comment: The easiest way to do it it's using JQuery Upload plug in. Here you can find how to upload and send data at the same time https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data